# SQL COUNT(Column) Counts also the null value which is wrong

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm creating a total details in my project but I'm having a problem regarding the "COUNT" in my query. It also calculates the null. What I want is, count the column with values only other than that, the query will not count the null column.

Here's my code

```
SELECT COUNT(columnName) as TotalColumnValue FROM tblName

| columnName| 
|      value|
|           |
|      value|
|      value|
```

so the result count would be 3 and not 4 because the value is null.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: COUNT will not count the NULL values, Its may be empty string in your data

Comment: I agree to Abdul. Please check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx  SQL Server Count() function does not count NULL values unless you use it as COUNT(*)    In your case probably you have empty string values which is different than NULL. If you execute a SELECT statement, you will see the value in SSMS as NULL not as ''

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, a `IS NOT NULL` condition like mentioned in all the answers is not necessary since count(columnName) will not count null values. So basically it enough to just filter empty string values and just specify the column in the count.

```
SELECT COUNT(columnName) as TotalColumnValue
FROM tblNam
WHERE columnName <> ''
```

Note -> to the question you've asked on the comments. `<>` means `!=` or in words - `NOT EQUAL`

Comment: What do you mean by <>?

Comment: I found your code simple and more helpful. :) Thank you @sagi :)

Comment: <> means != right? what if they are equal? == ? I'm just wondering man. :)

Comment: @mark No problem friend:) Yes, I wrote it on the answer. For equal you should use a single `=` not two, and I didn't understand the question, if equal it will count the rows where its an empty string.

Comment: Thank you man, I should continue now on my task. God bless! +

Answer (score 4):

If the value is really `NULL`, then `COUNT` should be excluding that row. Maybe it's not `NULL` but an empty string`''`. Try adding a `NULLIF` in your column:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(columnName VARCHAR(10) NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('value'), ('value'), ('value'), ('');

SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(columnName, '')) FROM tbl;
```

Or you can filter for empty strings:

```
SELECT COUNT(columnName) FROM tbl WHERE columnNameIS NOT NULL AND columnName <> ''
```

Comment: But if you said the count should exclude this row, why do you filter them?

Comment: Only `NULL` values are excluded by `COUNT`. Empty strings `''` are not. So you have to filter them in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Yes, you have to filter empty string, not null values.

Answer (score 2):

Adding where function solve your issue. :)

```
SELECT COUNT(columnName) as TotalColumnValue FROM tblName where columnName is not null
```

Comment: may i know what database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You need to exclude both `NULL` and `empty string ''`.

```
SELECT COUNT(columnName) as TotalColumnValue FROM tblName
WHERE columnName <> '';
```

Comment: What do you mean by <>?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the number of different values (not counting repeating values) use 
`SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(columnName) AS TotalColumnValue FROM tblName WHERE columnName IS NOT NULL`